# clearing all elements from Javascript knockout observableArray. Items remain causing duplicates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create an `observableArray` of "`Board`" objects to populate a view.

I can currently add new `Board` objects to the array after each timed page refresh. But instead of clearing the array and then adding new boards from the foreach loop, it just adds to the existing ones causing duplicates.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshPage();
});

function refreshPage() {
    getGames();
    setTimeout(refreshPage, 10000);
    console.log("Page refreshed");
};

function Board(data) {
    this.gameChannel = ko.observable(data.GameChannel);
    this.HomeTeamImage = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamImage);
    this.HomeTeamName = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamName);
    this.HomeBeerPrice = ko.observable(data.HomeBeerPrice);
    this.HomeTeamArrow = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamArrow);
    this.HomeBeer = ko.observable(data.HomeBeer);
    this.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(data.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.AwayTeamArrow = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamArrow);
    this.AwayBeerPrice = ko.observable(data.AwayBeerPrice);
    this.AwayTeamName = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamName);
    this.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(data.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.AwayBeer = ko.observable(data.AwayBeer);
    this.awayTeamImage = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamImage);
    this.FullScore = ko.computed(function() {
        return data.HomeTeamScore + " | " + data.AwayTeamScore;
    }, this);
}

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.gameCollection = ko.observableArray([]);
}

getGames = function() {
    var _vm = new vm();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Dashboard/PopulateMonitor/",
        error: errorFunc,
        success: function(data) {
            _vm.gameCollection = [];
            $.each(data, function() {
                _vm.gameCollection.push(new Board(this));
            });
        }
    });

    function errorFunc() {
        alert("Error, could not load gameboards");
    }
    ko.applyBindings(_vm);
}
```

The issue appears within the `getGames()` function on or around the line

```
_vm.gameCollection = [];
```

I appreciate any help available. Not very well versed with Knockout.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you're calling `getGames` you're creating a new '_vm':

```
getGames = function () {
    var _vm = new vm();
```

Move `var _vm = new vm();` to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _vm = new vm(); // <-- HERE
    refreshPage();
});
```

Some lines have to be moved too, see the snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  _vm = new vm();
  refreshPage();
});


function refreshPage() {

  getGames();
  setTimeout(refreshPage, 10000);
  console.log("Page refreshed");

};


function Board(data) {
  this.gameChannel = ko.observable(data.GameChannel);
  this.HomeTeamImage = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamImage);
  this.HomeTeamName = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamName);
  this.HomeBeerPrice = ko.observable(data.HomeBeerPrice);
  this.HomeTeamArrow = ko.observable(data.HomeTeamArrow);
  this.HomeBeer = ko.observable(data.HomeBeer);
  this.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(data.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice);
  this.AwayTeamArrow = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamArrow);
  this.AwayBeerPrice = ko.observable(data.AwayBeerPrice);
  this.AwayTeamName = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamName);
  this.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(data.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice);
  this.AwayBeer = ko.observable(data.AwayBeer);
  this.awayTeamImage = ko.observable(data.AwayTeamImage);
  this.FullScore = ko.computed(function() {
    return data.HomeTeamScore + " | " + data.AwayTeamScore;
  }, this);
}


function vm() {
  var self = this;
  self.gameCollection = ko.observableArray([]);
  ko.applyBindings(this);
}


getGames = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    // placeholder:
    url: 'data:application/json;utf8,[]',
    //url: "/Dashboard/PopulateMonitor/",
    error: errorFunc,
    success: function(data) {
      _vm.gameCollection.removeAll();
      $.each(data, function() {
        _vm.gameCollection.push(new Board(this));
      });
    }
  });

  function errorFunc() {
    alert("Error, could not load gameboards");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After that change i get the error "_vm is declared but is never used". I am assuming it is out of scope from the getGames() method

Comment: @DanielBrown, thank you, I've updated my answer. Please notice comments in the code. As I do not have the actual data, I used a placeholder.

Comment: What exactly is the point of the placeholder variable you have commented out?

Comment: @DanielBrown, I had to receive some data to make the snippet work, so I replaced your actual url with mine, please ignore this part, keep your url there.

Comment: I switched the line `_vm.gameCollection = [];` to `_vm.gameCollection.removeAll();` provided by user @adiga on the other solution and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- You shouldn't call `applyBindings` more than once. So, move it outside of your `setTimeout`.
- `_vm.gameCollection = []` won't work. To clear your `observableArray`, use [`removeAll`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#replace-remove-and-removeall). You can also set it to an empty array like this: `_vm.gameCollection([])`
- Also, if you want to call the same function after an interval of time, you can make use of [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Here's a minimal version of your code. Click on `Run code snippet` to test it out. I have created a `counter` variable which updates `gameCollection` with new `data` every second.

```js
let counter = 0;

function refreshPage() {
  getGames();
  console.log("Page refreshed");
};

function Board(data) {
  this.gameChannel = ko.observable(data.GameChannel);
}

function vm() {
  var self = this;
  self.gameCollection = ko.observableArray([]);
}

getGames = function() {
  let data = [
  {
     GameChannel: `GameChannel ${++counter}`
  },
  {
     GameChannel: `GameChannel ${++counter}`
  }];

  _vm.gameCollection.removeAll(); // <- Change here
  
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    _vm.gameCollection.push(new Board(item));
  });
}

var _vm = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(_vm); // this needs to be only called once per page (or element)

setInterval(refreshPage, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: gameCollection -->
<span data-bind="text: gameChannel"></span><br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this solution I receive an "unable to get property 'nodetype' of undefined or null reference" error. Do I need anything wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` tag and as I need my ajax call in the getGames method I put your `data.forEach...` function within the ajax succeed method if that is correct?

Comment: You have to move `ko.applyBindings` inside `$(document).ready()` and `data.forEach` needs to be within the success callback of your ajax and tweak according to your needs. But again, this is minimal working version version of your code.